# modules view in suitecrm is empty while search works fine

Tags: caching, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using suitecrm (a sugarcrm fork) version 5.3.3, when I click on "contacts" or any other module, at the upper menu, I see nothing.
however, when clicking on "serach" with empty parameters I do get the full list of contacts.

any idea what could cause such a bug? possibly a caching issue??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question that I think you're trying to ask is you are not getting list view of any module when click on any module from the navigation bar but when you do search with empty parameter you are getting the list .

you can check your `config_override.php` file for Disable Automatic Searches status

```
$sugar_config['save_query'] = 'populate_only';
```

1. populate_only :- Forces a user to perform a search when they access a listview rather than loading the results from their last search .
2. no :- Discards the previous search and executes a search with no criteria .
3. all :-Populates the last search and executes it

For more info on this please refer the below links

1. [Common Performance Tweaks](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Knowledge_Base/02Administration/100Troubleshooting/Common_Performance_Tweaks/)
2. [Advanced Configuration Options](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/01_Sugar_Ultimate/Sugar_Ultimate_6.5/Administration_Guide/14_Advanced_Configuration_Options/)

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you than you can accept the answer or vote it up

Comment: sorry, it just took me a long time to notice the answer, it was perfect and solved the problem